# Regarding DESFIRE EV1 8k smart card

Tags: nfc, smartcard, javacard, mifare

I am using desfire ev1 8k smart card, here i am not able to read write operations through card. because of file structure, can any one help for this, i got struck here please.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the Desfire specification?

Answer (score 2):

As you know, specifications are under [NDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement). But there's some open source library which manipulate Mifare card as this one:
http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Libfreefare

You could start by looking at this lib.

Comment: @Kumar Swamy, Is it useful ?

Comment: Take it easy Laurent, questions without accepted answers gain more upvotes as more people will look at them - sometimes I don't get accepts for days (weeks/months/years)... 4 hours is a bit short :)

Comment: Thanks for replay,  I am using desfire ev1 8k card. If you have any sample code or document please send to my mail id(kumarsjavadev@gmail.com), so that i can proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Documents are under NDA. Nobody can send you document. You have to request documents to NXP directly. Otherwise have a look a Libfreefare library.

Comment: Libfreefare is a huge code. For a Desfire beginner it is easier to start with a smaller code that does the same. In my Desfire class you find everything in one CPP file: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1096861/DIY-electronic-RFID-Door-Lock-with-Battery-Backup